# Sample file not installed in another user account's personal folder

Tags: windows, user-accounts, my-documents, installshield

I work on an install team that uses InstallShield. I have a component that has a sample XML file set as a key file that is to be installed on a user's machine in their personal folder. When installing on a specific account, I see the sample file in the account's personal folder (My Docs). If I then log out and log in to a different account, I do not see this sample file in that account's personal folder. This seems to make some sense, but then I tried running my company's program or repairing it and I still don't see the sample file.

I am wondering if there is a setting for the component that I am missing in InstallShield, or a way to set it up, that would install this file when an account other than the one it was install with tried to run the application that the component is associated with.

Comment: What is the OS? in windows it is supposed to work this way, that is why some programs have "Install for all users" or "install for just this user". These user folders are only easily available at the user level to the user they belong to. The admin can get to them, which is why some installs require admin privelage to install. If the item to be installed is not a user only item, could you install it where it will be accessable to everything?  or install it for all users with admin privelage (all uses and the default?  so it is all new users also)

Comment: Windows Vista and higher are the OSs I'm running this program on. Although the suggestions you mentioned are understandable, they aren't quite the option I was looking for, but I was considering some of them as a last resort. What I did notice on a webpage was something called Advertised Shortcuts. For some reason, reading about advertised shortcuts on InstallShield help, it seemed like it was something different than what this other webpage was talking about. If I mark the component as advertised, it should see the component is missing and repair the install so that the sample installs.

Comment: (continued) This is something I will try shortly and see if it actually works this way.